# rake assets:precompile fails – file exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've stumbled onto a bit of a weird issue with my Rails app...

Until recently, my app has been running fine. Now, when trying to precompile assets, I'm getting a 'rake aborted!' error.

Even though I've removed all assets, I'm getting a `File exists` error...

```
My-MacBook-Pro-2:myapp myname$ ls public/assets
ls: public/assets: No such file or directory

My-MacBook-Pro-2:myapp myname$ rake assets:precompile --trace
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.8.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.9.0
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.8.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.9.0
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
File exists - /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/public/assets/myapp
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `mkdir'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `fu_mkdir'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:221:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `reverse_each'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `block in mkdir_p'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `each'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `mkdir_p'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:40:in `block in write_asset'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:38:in `tap'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:38:in `write_asset'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:24:in `block in compile'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:212:in `block in each_logical_path'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:200:in `block (2 levels) in each_file'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each_entry'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:198:in `block in each_file'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each_file'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:210:in `each_logical_path'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p...]
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:55:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `sh'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:82:in `ruby'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `ruby'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
My-MacBook-Pro-2:myapp myname$
```

I've tried removing the `public/assets` directory manually, using `rm -rf public/assets`, and, I've also ran `rake assets:clean` successfully – and the issue is still not resolved.

I'm trying to pinpoint what could cause the issue. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What more do you need? Happy to provide more information... fairly simple issue... running rake assets:precompile, and it says a File exists – and throws an error... even though I've removed the entire assets directory.

Comment: anything at all that will help us solve the issue... any info, say, about what sort of app you have written, what assets you have. whether it worked in the past and has stopped working (and what you changed in between), anything you can tell us so that we an reproduce the error on our machines...?

Comment: Think of it like this: If *I* run `rake assets:precompile` I don't get that error... what do you need to tell me to do so that I get that same error?

Comment: Gotchya. I went ahead and updated the original post with a more detailed error message, as well as my gem file – and some additional background.

Comment: did you check public assets folder was actually deleted? `ls public`

Comment: Yes – I've confirmed that it was deleted. So weird!

Comment: Added full trace, to provide additional information/clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up resolving this issue –

Due to the lack of specificity in the error log, it was difficult to pinpoint. The issue was, in my `/fonts` directory, I had a file named 'myapp'... with no suffix... this caused Rails to puke.

Comment: Cool. odd error for that. I hate unspecific error messages :P